# Passing objects as parameters in SugarORM

Tags: java, android, sugarorm

I have an object extending SugarRecord that looks like this:

```
public class SavedDraft extends SugarRecord {
private String name;
private String difficulty;
private int sport_id;
private LocalActivity localActivity;

    public SavedDraft() {
}

public SavedDraft(String name, String difficulty, int ID, LocalActivity localActivity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.difficulty = difficulty;
    this.sport_id = ID;
    this.localActivity = localActivity;
}
}
```

The problem is that I always get a null object when I try to get the localActivity object from the database (see: SavedDraft.findById(SavedDraft.class, 1).getLocalActivity()), and I'm just wondering if it's possible to save objects as parameters in SugarORM at all.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a relationship and you would need the LocalActivity to extend SugarRecord also.

See the documentation of Book and Author: http://satyan.github.io/sugar/creation.html